# Swallowing mucus gaves me sore throat?

Tags: common-cold, swallow-swallowing, mucus-phlegm, sore-throat, nasal-drip

I have had a common cold for a week. I had lot of mucus (or phlegm, I don't know what the correct term is) in my nose. My throat was ok back then. Yesterday before sleeping I couldn't avoid swallowing some mucus because, it just got into my throat, and I felt like it got stuck in my throat.

I don't have any way of knowing more precisely where the mucus is, and suddenly I felt a presence of a substance in my throat, I thought it was the mucus that got swallowed. This has happened me many times before and now, and those times, it causes sore throat (or odynophagia) my throat hurts a little. My explanation for getting a sore throat afterwards is that the mucus has bacteria and they then thrive on my throat.

Does it mechanically make sense that mucus on my nose could arrive to my throat, or am I confusing sensations?

Answer (score 4):

Naturally, your nasal passageways and sinuses drain down into the back of your throat - and you swallow the drainage without even realizing it.  In the diagram below, it's the oropharynx where your mouth and your nasal/sinus passageways come together.

Sore throats are a common [symptom of the common cold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_cold).  You may notice the pain more when swallowing the increased mucus from your cold.

[image]